# How can make my Jasmine test reach this callback inside mergeMap?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, jwt, karma-jasmine

I'm working with Angular6 and I'm trying to make my Jasmine test reach the callback inside mergeMap bellow, but after days of work I just can't do it.

[image: callback inside mergeMap highlighted]

My test returns correctly the refresh method, but it just doesn't seem to follow through the pipe.

This is the full method where I'm testing:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    if (
      this.jwtInterceptor.isWhitelistedDomain(req) &&
      !this.jwtInterceptor.isBlacklistedRoute(req)
    ) {
      const newRequest = req.clone();
      return next.handle(newRequest).pipe(
        tap(() => {
          const token = this.jwtHelper.tokenGetter();
          if (token) {
            const expirationTime = this.jwtHelper
              .getTokenExpirationDate()
              .getTime();
            const expirationLeft = expirationTime - Date.now();
            const expired =
              expirationLeft > 0 && expirationLeft < 5 * 60 * 1000;
            if (expired && !this.isUpdating) {
              this.isUpdating = true;
              return this.refresh().pipe(
                mergeMap(() => { // this is the unreachable part
                  return this.jwtInterceptor.intercept(req, next);
                })
              );
            }
          }
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
            this.router.navigate([this.config.routeToGoIfNotLoggedIn]);
          }
          return throwError(err);
        })
      );
    } else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
```

Here my this.refresh() method returned:

```
refresh(): Observable<any> {
    const refreshObservable = this.authAPI.refreshToken();
    const refreshSubject = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
    refreshSubject.subscribe(
      data => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', data.jwt);
        this.isUpdating = false;
      },
      err => {
        this.isUpdating = false;
        this.userLoggedService.removeUserLoggedAndToken();
      }
    );

    refreshObservable.subscribe(refreshSubject);
    return refreshSubject;
  }
}
```

and this is my this.authAPI.refreshToken() fired inside refresh():

```
  refreshToken() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.config.baseAPIUrl}refreshToken`);
  }
```

The http call is correctly catch within my httpTestingController and the final expectation is to have this.jwtInterceptor.intercept(req, next) fired.

This is my spec for the part I'm failing:

```
it('should call Refresh method if token is expiring in 5 minutes', () => {
    const nowInMillisec = Number(new Date());
    const FourMinutesFromNow = nowInMillisec + 4 * 60000;
    spyOn(
      jwtService,
      'getTokenExpirationDate'
    ).and.returnValue(new Date(FourMinutesFromNow));

    const jwtInterceptor = TestBed.get(JwtInterceptor);
    const spyOnJwtInterceptor = spyOn(jwtInterceptor, 'intercept');

    dummyService.fakeHttpCall().subscribe();
    httpTestingController.expectOne(
      `${MockAuthConfig.baseAPIUrl}user/fake-call`
    );

    const callbackHttpFired = httpTestingController.expectOne(
      `${MockAuthConfig.baseAPIUrl}refreshToken`
    );
    expect(callbackHttpFired.request.url).toEqual(
      `${MockAuthConfig.baseAPIUrl}refreshToken`
    );
    expect(spyOnJwtInterceptor).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this spy is never fired... :(
  });
```

Any ideas??
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `done()` is vital here since the call of `subscribe` is asynchronous, the rest of your test is runned before the `subscribe` exits. Also, you should test the `refresh` method separatly. First test that the `refresh` was called in the `intercept`

The signature should then be changed with

```
it('should call Refresh method if token is expiring in 5 minutes', (done) => {    
  ...
  jwtInterceptor.intecept.subscribe(() => { 
    expect(spyOnJwtInterceptor).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
  });
}
```

So the test method will wait until done() is called. And the expect will go as planed.

Comment: That makes really sense. Thanks! But I'm having some trouble with my spies.
The spy on `refresh` isn't triggered, even though trough console.logs I can see that the code clearly fires `refresh`.
And `jwtInterceptor.intercept().subscribe(() ...` returns `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

I'll keep on investigating it and come back... :/

Comment: You must remove the spy: const spyOnJwtInterceptor = spyOn(jwtInterceptor, 'intercept');